# Cannot SSH into Kubuntu box without password

Tags: ssh

I am trying to set password-less logins **to** my desktop **from** my server so that a bash script on the server could `scp` backups over to the desktop. The desktop is running Kubuntu 12.10, and the server is running some Redhat derivative. My desktop's IP address does not change (not on the big bad internet, and not on the LAN). I can SSH in from the server to the desktop just fine:

```
[remote]$ ssh backup@my-ip-address
backup@my-ip-address's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.10 (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-25-generic x86_64)
...
[dotandesktop]$ exit
Connection to my-ip-address closed.
[remote]$
```

I have `scp`ed the `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file from the remote server to the desktop. I then `cat`ed the file into the desktop's `.ssh/authorized_keys` key file with the `>>` append operator. I believe that I have the correct permissions for everything on the desktop:

```
[dotandesktop]$ sudo ls -la | grep  .ssh
drwx------ 2 backupuser backupuser 4096 Apr  7 13:01 .ssh
[dotandesktop]$ ls -la .ssh
total 12
drwx------ 2 backupuser backupuser 4096 Apr  7 13:01 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 backupuser backupuser 4096 Apr  7 13:58 ..
-rw------- 1 backupuser backupuser 1211 Apr  7 13:58 authorized_keys
```

And on the server:

```
[remote]$ ls -la | grep .ssh
drwx------ 2 fschafer fschafer     4096 Apr  7 04:05 .ssh
[remote]$ ls -la .ssh
total 24
drwx------ 2 fschafer fschafer 4096 Apr  7 04:05 .
drwx--x--x 4 fschafer fschafer 4096 Apr  7 06:05 ..
-rw------- 1 fschafer fschafer 1608 Feb 25 04:51 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 fschafer fschafer 1675 Apr  7 04:05 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 fschafer fschafer  405 Apr  7 04:05 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 fschafer fschafer  791 Apr  7 04:40 known_hosts
[remote]$
```

Additionally, from my SSH config file:

```
[dotandesktop]$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep "RSAAuthentication\|PubkeyAuthentication"
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
```

However, when I try to SSH into the desktop from the server, it still asks me for my password. What else should I check?

Comment: Did you create a ssh key with a passphrase?

Comment: No, no passphrase!

Answer (score 1):

You did it the wrong way. You need the private key on the client and the public key on the server in the `authorized_keys` file.

**Edit from Oli:** I'll add that you'd do yourself a ton of favours by just using the toolset provided for you.
Namely: `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: I'm trying to SSH in _from_ the server _to_ the desktop in order to move server backups to the desktop.

Comment: I just tried with ssh-copy-id (from the server _to_ my desktop) but still, when I try to SSH into the desktop from the server I am prompted for my password. Of course, I used the `-i` option to select `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: It's kind of confusing to use the terms server and client in that way. It doesn't make a lot of sense to copy your backup from the server to your desktop as a server is something that is hosting services and a client uses them. You should pull the backups from the server, not push them to the client.